# Date Warehouse: when the cleaning and transforming is performed?

Tags: data-warehouse

I am reading a book "Modeling the agile data warehouse with data vault" by H. Hultgren. He states:

> EDW represents what did happen - not what should have happened

When does the cleaning and possible transforming is performed? Under transforming I mean stadartization f the values, for example, sex column can contain only two possible values 'f' and 'm' and not 'female' or 'male' or 0 or 1)?

Comment: If you are importing data through ETL, that is one place to do it. Or you can use some other kind of data cleansing tool. This is a very general question. It depends on the architecture of your data warehouse. What prompts the question?

Comment: I am not sure why it should depend on the architecture of a data warehouse. Having raw data, one wants to build a data warehouse to perform analysis. However, in order to perform the analysis, data should be standartize (example with sex). Hultgren mentions that EDW represents what happened already, meaning no transformation or cleaning should be done because then it will represent what should have happened.

Comment: For example you might have a data warehouse that loads data and tries to automatically clean it or you might have an architecture where every single 'bad' record goes to an approval area to be cleaned by a person. I can assure you in the real world, no business user wants to have to pick from 6 values for gender. That's a very broad statement about an EDW. It might mean for example that you should reflect what happened in source systems _without adding adjustments or journals_ to make the data look better.

Comment: The other thing is you might be loading data from three different systems, and these three different representations are completely valid in each system, but an end user doesn't want to have to pick from 6 choices - they want the data to be cleansed. I'm thinking maybe this is a data vault specific thing since it is all about replicating the source systems, and I guess in this case you would treat the data vault as an ODS and cleanse it on the way into the reporting star schema

Comment: Post you last comment as a main answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are importing data through ETL, that is one place to do it. Or you can use some other kind of data cleansing tool. This is a very general question. It depends on the architecture of your data warehouse.

For example you might have a data warehouse that loads data and tries to automatically clean it or you might have an architecture where every single 'bad' record goes to an approval area to be cleaned by a person. I can assure you in the real world, no business user wants to have to pick from 6 values for gender.

The other thing is you might be loading data from three different systems, and these three different representations are completely valid in each system, but an end user doesn't want to have to pick from 6 choices - they want the data to be cleansed.

I'm thinking maybe this statement

> > EDW represents what did happen - not what should have happened

is a data vault specific thing since DV is all about modelling and storing the source system data no matter how the schema changes, and I guess in this case you would treat the data vault as an ODS and preserve the data as-as, then cleanse it on the way into the reporting star schema